# Fetch matched documents if array element match condition otherwise fetch all documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Here is my mongo document look like

```
[
  {
    name: "Alex",
    role: ["player","coach"]
  },
  {
    name: "John",
    role: ["player"],
    
  },
  {
    name: "Jack",
    role: ["coach"],
    
  },
  {
    name: "Smith",
    role: [],
    
  },
  
]
```

my query is that if any document match with array element then it should return that element.but, if i pass role name and any document role field has empty array then it shoul return all the time.

for eg:
if i pass role as ['player'] then it shoul return all document that role array contain this role as well as empty role array document should also return

so, it should return {'alex','John','smith'} named document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with `$or` operator to fulfill either of these conditions:

1. Match any of the elements from the input array with the element in the `role` array field.
2. `role` field is an empty array.

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $or: [
      {
        $ne: [
          {
            $setIntersection: [
              "$role",
              [
                "player"
              ] // Input
            ]
          },
          []
        ]
      },
      {
        $eq: [
          "$role",
          []
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xtELuROhamn)